# Why people use sum function in single cell references for no apparent reason? Am I missing something here?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have seen people use SUM in calcs when there is no need to use it and I just assumed that they didn't know what they were doing but I just downloaded a template from excel and they use it as well. So I am wondering maybe there is a good reason to do that and I am completely missing something.
Example:

```
=IF(SUM(A20)>0,SUM((A20*E20)-F20),"")
```

Why not just:

```
=IF(A20>0, (A20*E20)-F20, "")
```

Comment: how is this a programming question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two reasons why people use sum in such situation:

1. They just don't know better
2. As error prevention: if any of the cells contains a string, using them for any mathematical operation will result in an `#VALUE!` error. Wrapping it with `SUM`will cast a string to a 0.

While the latter has some use, it's normally better to ensure consistent data - or handle it more explicit in the formula, e.g. `IF(ISTEXT(A1),0,A1)`.

I do not see any reason why someone would wrap the result of a formula in a SUM...

Answer (score 1):

I have spoken to a few users who have habitually been doing this, to find out why.

The typical answer is that they did not realise that they could type a formula directly into a cell by pressing equals.

So, instead of pressing the equals sign, they have learned (or been shown) to press the **ƒx** button at the top, find the first suitable function (SUM), then click on the source cell, and type the formula into the dialogue box.

Answer (score 0):

I thnk that the only way you would justify this sort of use is if the cells might contain text, e.g. if you use

`=A1+A2`

then that will give an error if either cell contains text whereas using `=SUM(A1,A2)` won't give an error.......but that doesn't apply to your example because the second SUM function would still give an error if any of those cells contained text.

This is simply bad usage, as is any use of + within SUM function. Unfortunately Microsoft's excel suggestions contain several errors like this.